# jQuery filter by an attribute value

Tags: jquery, attributes, filter

```
<div class="selectedColumns" >
<a href="#" attributeid="19" >Driver License State</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="21" >Email</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="23" >Experience Level</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="26" >First Name</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="71" >Is Account Enabled</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="39" >Last Contacted Date</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="40" >Last Name</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="41" >Middle Name</a>
<a href="#" attributeid="6">Carrier</a>
</div>
```

I have a collection of links. Each link has an attributeid property. I would like to filter by attribute value. So in the links above if I have a value of 41 it would return the Middle Name link.

```
var link = $('.selectedColumns a:[attributeid==' + $(this).val() + ']');
```

This did not work?

Comment: Note that using custom attributes results in [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) documents in HTML4 and below. In HTML5, you can have valid custom attributes if they start with `data-` (e.g., `data-attributeid`). Those are still invalid in earlier versions, but hey, so is your current one. :-)

Comment: @T.J. - I realize the w3c says that this is a no no, but when you build 'software' that is heavily dependent on jQuery you use custom attributes all the time and don't worry about validation.

Comment: I realize what you're saying, and I agree with you, in fact *so does W3C*, otherwise they wouldn't be added in HTML5.  What he's saying is if you're going to use *something*, why not go ahead and pick a `data-something` attribute name that *will* be valid moving forward?

Comment: Following on from what Nick said: Yes, they're functional, I've never met a browser that didn't handle them correctly, and I use custom attributes all the time. It's just that [validation](http://validator.w3.org) *(that's a link, as it was in my earlier comment; stoopid StackOverflow not underlining links)* is a very helpful tool, so setting yourself up so you can use it once you switch to the new doctype is a Good Thing(tm).

Comment: Wow so many grammar mistakes in my last comment, leaving it anyway in case someone finds it helpful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use a single = instead of 2. Also, the : shoudn't be there afaik

```
var link = $('.selectedColumns a[attributeid=' + $(this).val() + ']');
```

Answer (score 40):

Not claiming this is any more elegant, but using filter() on a collection allows much more flexibility on what you can match on, and is a little less error prone than string concatenation.

```
var matching = $('.selectedColumns a').filter(function(){
                   return $(this).attr('attributeid') == 41
                });
    matching.prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 21):

There's no need for the `:` or double `=` in your [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), it should just be:

```
$('.selectedColumns a[attributeid=' + $(this).val() + ']');
```

Also if you're using invalid attributes, consider using [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) which *are* valid in HTML5, for example `data-id` instead of `attributeid`.