# Javascript Regex matching xml tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I am going to match something like `<textEntryInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE" expectedLength="15"/>`, and I want it to be occur once only.
When I use `/<textEntryInteraction [^>]+\/>/g` to search and match the tags, I don't know why `pattern.test(xml)` return false.

However, if i use `/<textEntryInteraction [^>]+\/>/`, it return true.

Can anyone helps me?

Comment: Why aren't you using an XML parser? Required reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @MattBall If there are more than one root node for the XML, Would it be possible to detected by XML parser?

Comment: are you sure it returns false? here I tried your pattern and it returns true. maybe you should try "ig" instead of "g" to ignore case issue.

Comment: If there's more than one root node, you don't have valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would seriously consider looking at [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead of regex for this type of work. You can do something like this.

```
var $xml = $($.parseXML(yourXMLcontent));
var $textEntries = $xml.find('textEntryInteraction');
```

You can then [filter your textEntries by attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547363/jquery-filter-by-an-attribute-value).

[filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: If textEntryInteraction do not exist, can I handle this case?

Comment: Yes, the function "find" and "filter" both return arrays. Just check the length of the return value.